can't change partition size
I have a problem with Ubuntu 24 running in a VirtualBox machine. It seemed like I assigned not enough hard drive space and now the space is full. I extended the virtual drive size, but it just added more free space that's apparently not assigned to a partition. Looks like this now:

It says rpool not mounted, but when I run the command df -T /users/f/foo/file.txt to check which partition the file is on, it says rpool. I get an error when mounting it and the resize option is greyed out. Partition 3 can only be made smaller and bpool can't be resizes. So what's happening here?

Install gparted via
sudo apt-get install gparted

You can extend partitions in the software
